# Cache-friendly Code

Tags: c, memory-efficient

I recently came across this example while reading some introduction to C text. There was no explanation to why the codes below are different when it comes to cache friendliness, and I can't figure out the difference. The text goes like this:

Comparing these two codes:

```
// cache-friendly
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
    {
        a[i][j] += 10;
    }
}
```

VS

```
// not cache-friendly
int i, j;
for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        a[i][j] += 10;
    }
}
```

Does anybody see why code A is cache-friendly compared to code B?

Comment: It is about the locality of the data you're looking at. A 2D array is a contiguous block of memory, and it is accessed in row-major form. So the elements in a single row are contiguous, the elements in a column are separate.

Comment: Your processor instruction cache can predict sequencial array access better than something it considers random.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you, that clarifies everything. If you would like to post that as an answer I will take it.

Comment: (Despite having marked it as a duplicate) In your case the array is so small it will comfortably fit in L1 cache, so it shouldn't cause a significant difference.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I know in this case the are no practical differences, but my question was more conceptually oriented. In any case, I already looked at the question you pointed as mine being a  duplicate of, thank you.